# how to represent enter key as char in c Language?

Tags: c

I have tried this :

```
switch(c)
case 13 : {printf("enter pressed");break;}
```

and this :

```
switch(c)
case '\n' : {printf("enter pressed");break;}
```

but It didn't work out

Comment: This code doesn't compile, as your `switch` statement is wrong.

Comment: Did you try asking the user for input first with a function like `fgets()`, `fscanf()`, `scanf()` and the like?

Comment: What is `c`? Where do you get its value from?

Comment: I just want sb to tell me the ascii value of the enter key . Leave the rest to me

Comment: ASCII does not encode keys. In other words the enter key does not *have* an ASCII value. Different libraries tell you about keys in different ways, this is why I asked how you get a value for `c`. If you are looking for ASCII values, I'd try LF (10/0x0A) and CR (13/0x0D) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart).

Comment: @MagnusHoff what should I do when I want to make sure that the user pressed Enter in this case ?!

Comment: Sorry, you haven't given me enough information to help you. I need to know how you get your value for `c` in order to be able to help you.

Comment: using this function : getc();

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `'\r'` instead.
The 'Enter' key represent Carriage Return that is the same as `'\r'`.

Answer (score 0):

"Enter" represents a new line character in C language.
So you can use its ascii value i.e. 10 for its representation.
Eg :

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

Try this code :

```
int main()
{
   char ch = '\n';
   printf("ch = %d\n", ch);
}
```

Later you can use the following code as a test for switching '/n'

```
int main()
{
  char ch = '\n';
  switch(ch)
  {
    case '\n' : 
           printf("Enter pressed\n");
    break;
    default : 
       //code
  }
}
```

Comment: is the enter ascii value is 10 ?!

Comment: @BillalTeiba - Yes it is. You can google it or use "man ascii" if
you are using linux platform

Comment: case 10 : printf("enter pressed");

Comment: can i put it this way ?!

Comment: Yes you can. I've made some changes to my post. You can do it that  
way also.

Comment: But use "break" after your case to avoid messing up with other cases.

Answer (score 0):

This program reads from standard input and writes "enter pressed" whenever a newline occurs in the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    for (;;) {
        c = getc(stdin);
        switch (c) {
        case '\n':
            printf("enter pressed\n");
            break;
        case EOF:
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

You might be missing the trailing `\n` in your `printf`-call, causing the message to be buffered for output but maybe not flushed so it appears on the screen.